# Как обратиться из класса1, к переменной экземпляра класса2?

Tags: java, syntax

Как обратиться из класса1, к переменной экземпляра класса2?

Например, от сюда обращаемся:

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(object1.a); //ошибка
        }

    }
}
```

А класс, в котором объявлена переменная object1, находиться в том же пакете:

```
public class Solution {
    int a = 555;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution object1 = new Solution();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде так.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
       Solution object1 = new Solution();
       System.out.println(object1.a);
    }
}
```

Область видимости переменной. Метод `main` не видит вашу переменную `object1` по этому у вас и происходит ошибка.